# How can I store data before one page closed in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

so far as I know, if you close or refresh a page,the hook '**beforedestroy**' and '**destroyed**' in Vue would not be triggered.So maybe I can use

> window.onbeforeunload = function() { ... }

And here's the code

```
mounted() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                window.localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(this.form))
            }
        }
```

However, What I store is undefined. So I think that the instance has been destroyed when the function is called. In this way, this.form can't be accessed.Is there any other way?

Comment: You could just save the data to `localStorage` whenever `form` changes, using a deep watcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing `this` keyword by defining an anonymous function, use an arrow function instead:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(this.form))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think of any way to store data before a page is closed because it's browsers action
i guess you can sotre data each x second which is easy but you can't know when a user closes the page because it cuts the connection between the client/user and the server.
So the best solution i can think of is saving data every X second.

Answer (score 0):

Try using vue-persist (a library in vue), unlike the localStorage this will help you to retain the stored values even after the window is closed.